# custom body tag based on post category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a body class depending on post type and category.

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );

function custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'service_provider' == $post->post_type AND 'educational_services' == $post->post_category ) {
        $classes[] = 'body-purple';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

this returns this error -

Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/davedevj/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 394 class="">

so I put some extra code in:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );

function custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'service_provider' == $post->post_type AND 'educational_services' == $post->post_category ) {
        $classes[] = 'body-purple';
        return $classes;
    }
    else {
         $classes[] = '';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

if possible I need to do without the else statement.

But the main problem is that even this doesn't work. I have tried just leaving in the post_category part and not having the AND, just the if conditional - but no luck.

Comment: Working on a rewrite now.

Comment: hey is service_provider the key of some array ?

Comment: its a custom post type

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because there is no post_category property. Here's my version:

```
function wpse_custom_body_class( $classes ) {
     // Check user is on a single service_provider post.
     if ( ! is_singular( 'service_provider' ) )
         return $classes;     

     // Get categories assigned to post.
     $categories = get_the_category();

     // Check categories were found.
     if ( ! $categories )
         return $classes;

     foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
         if ( 'educational_services' == $category->name ) {
             $classes[] = 'body-purple'; 
         }
     }

     return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_custom_body_class' );
```

Comment: No that doesn't work - any ideas how to debug this? Can I output the current category to the browser windows to check what it is? I am a front end guy just getting my feet wet with PHP and back-end WP

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this isn't working however I believe the issue lies elsewhere. I replicated your setup on a local installation and this was successful.